# Issue with class being not Serilizable in Game, but works fine when Isolated

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedimage

So in a game I am making, I'm trying to send over an ArrayList of type Troop and ArrayList of type Tower over a socket, with both class Troop and Tower having a buffered Image. The game runs at 60 fps, and each time it sends over the two ArrayLists between both the server and client in the updateConnection() method. When I pulled out the Troop class and the Server and Client Classes, I am successfully able to send over the ArrayLists, but I get an error saying Troop is not sterilizable when it runs in the game. Below I included the Troop class, the server and client classes, the two classes that ran the test sending and receiving, and the method updateConnection() in the Game class:

```
public class Server{

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

JTextArea t;
JFrame f;

//constructor
public Server(){


    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);

    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(8790, 10); //8798 is a dummy port for testing, this can be changed. The 100 is the maximum people waiting to connect.
            try{
                //Trying to connect and have conversation
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                //t.append("Connection was terminated");
            }
    } catch (IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    t.append(" Waiting for someone to connect...");
    connection = server.accept();
    t.append(" Now connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

    t.append(" Streams are now setup ");
    f.setVisible(false);
    f.dispose();
}


        //  input.readObject();


public void closeConnection(){
    //t.append(" Closing Connections... ");
    try{
        output.close(); //Closes the output path to the client
        input.close(); //Closes the input path to the server, from the client.
        connection.close(); //Closes the connection between you can the client
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ObjectOutputStream getOutput(){
    return output;
}
public ObjectInputStream getInput(){
    return input;
}

public void sendObjects(Object obj){
    try {
        output.writeObject(obj);
        output.flush();
        output.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public Object receiveObjects(){
    try{
        return input.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

.

```
 public class Client extends JFrame{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;

JTextArea t;
JFrame f;

//constructor
public Client(String host){

    serverIP = host;

    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);

    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        //t.append("Connection was terminated");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Client(){

    serverIP = "127.0.0.1";

    f = new JFrame();
    f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    f.pack();

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new JTextArea();
    f.add(t, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setVisible(true);


    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        //t.append("Connection was terminated");
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}



//connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    t.append("Attempting connection...");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 8790);
    t.append("Connection Established! Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//set up streams
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    t.append(" The streams are now set up!");
    f.setVisible(false);
    f.dispose();
}


//Close connection
public void closeConnection(){
    //t.append(" Closing the connection!");
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ObjectOutputStream getOutput(){
    return output;
}
public ObjectInputStream getInput(){
    return input;
}

public void sendObjects(Object obj){
    try {
        output.writeObject(obj);
        output.flush();
        output.reset();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public Object receiveObjects(){
    try{
        return input.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

.

```
public class Troop implements Serializable{
private int x;
private int y;


private int health;
private int movSpeed;
private int movSpeedx;
private int movSpeedy;
private int cost;
private long deployCoolDown;
private int level;
private transient BufferedImage image;
private int size = 16;
private Handler handler;

/**
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param level
 * @param health
 * @param movSpeed
 * @param movSpeedx
 * @param movSpeedy
 * @param cost
 * @param deployCoolDown
 * @param image
 * 
 */

public Troop(int x, int y, int level, int health, int movSpeed, int movSpeedx, int movSpeedy, int cost, long deployCoolDown, BufferedImage image, Handler handler){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.level = level;
    this.health = health;
    this.movSpeed = movSpeed;
    this.movSpeedx = -movSpeed;
    this.movSpeedy = movSpeedy;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.deployCoolDown = deployCoolDown;
    this.image = image;
    this.handler = handler;

}
public void update(){
    Move();
    if(health <= 0){
        handler.getTroops().remove(this);
    }
}

public void checkX(){
    int z = 0;
    int tempMovSpeed = movSpeed;
    if(tempMovSpeed> 0){ //moving down
        int ty = (int) (y + tempMovSpeed + size + size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;
        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty) &&
                    !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty)){
            z = 1;
        }else{
            //System.out.println("collision moving down");
        }
    }

    tempMovSpeed = -movSpeed;

    if(tempMovSpeed < 0){ // up
        int ty = (int) (y + tempMovSpeed - size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty) &&
                    !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT,ty)){
            if(z == 1){
                z = 3;
            }
            else{
                z = 2;
            }
        }else{
            //System.out.println("collision moving up");
        }
    }

    //System.out.println(z);

    if(z == 0){
        //System.out.println("dead end?");
    }
    else if(z == 1){
        movSpeedy = movSpeed;
    }
    else if(z == 2){
        movSpeedy = -movSpeed;
    }
    else if(z == 3){
        Random r = new Random();
        int q = r.nextInt(2);
        if(q == 0){
            movSpeedy = movSpeed;
        }
        else{
            movSpeedy = -movSpeed;
        }
    }
}
public void checkY(){
    int z = 0;
    int tempMovSpeed = movSpeed;
    int tx = (int) (x + tempMovSpeed + size + size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;

    if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
            !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT)){
        z = 1;

    }

    tempMovSpeed = -movSpeed;
    tx = (int) (x + tempMovSpeed - size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;

    if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
            !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT)){
        if(z != 1){
            z = 2;
        }
        else{
            z = 3;
        }
    }
    if(z == 0){
        //System.out.println("dead end");
    }
    else if(z == 1){
        movSpeedx = movSpeed;
    }
    else if(z == 2){
        movSpeedx = -movSpeed;
    }
    else{
        Random r = new Random();
        int q = r.nextInt(1);
        if(q == 0){
            movSpeedx = movSpeed;
        }
        else{
            movSpeedx = -movSpeed;
        }
    }
}

protected boolean collisionWithTile(int x, int y){
    return !handler.getWorlds().get(handler.getGame().getLevel()).getTile(x, y).isPath();
}

public void render(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
}
public void Move(){
    if(movSpeedx > 0){ //moving right
            int tx = (int) (x + movSpeedx + size + size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;
            if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                    !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                        !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT)){
                x += movSpeedx;
            }else{
                x = tx * Tile.TILE_WIDTH - 3 * size /2;
                checkX();
                movSpeedx = 0;

            }
        }
    else if(movSpeedx < 0){ // left
        int tx = (int) (x + movSpeedx - size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT) &&
                    !collisionWithTile(tx, (int) (y + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT)){
            x += movSpeedx;
        }else{
            x = tx * Tile.TILE_WIDTH + Tile.TILE_WIDTH + size/2;
            checkX();
            movSpeedx = 0;
        }
    }

    if(movSpeedy > 0){ //moving down
        int ty = (int) (y + movSpeedy + size + size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;
        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty) &&
                    !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty)){
            y += movSpeedy;
        }else{
            //System.out.println("collision");
            y = ty * Tile.TILE_WIDTH - 3 * size /2;
            movSpeedy = 0;
            checkY();
        }
    }
    else if(movSpeedy < 0){ // up
        int ty = (int) (y + movSpeedy - size/2) / Tile.TILE_WIDTH;

        if(!collisionWithTile((int) (x) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty) &&
                !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty) &&
                    !collisionWithTile((int) (x + size/2) / Tile.TILE_HEIGHT, ty)){
            y += movSpeedy;
        }else{
            y = ty * Tile.TILE_WIDTH + Tile.TILE_WIDTH + size/2;
            movSpeedy = 0;
            checkY();
        }
    }

}



public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public int getSize(){
    return size;
}
public int getMovSpeed() {
    return movSpeed;
}
public void setMovSpeed(int movSpeed) {
    this.movSpeed = movSpeed;
}
public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void changeHealth(int health) {
    this.health += health;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public long getDeployCoolDown() {
    return deployCoolDown;
}

public void setDeployCoolDown(int deployCoolDown) {
    this.deployCoolDown = deployCoolDown;
}

 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)throws IOException{
     out.defaultWriteObject();
 }

 private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
     in.defaultReadObject();
 }


}
```

The method from Game (which is called 60 times a second):

```
private void updateConnection(){


        if(isClientActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                client.sendObjects(towers);
                System.out.println("sent towers: " + towers.size());
            }else{
                client.sendObjects(troops);
                System.out.println("sent troops: " + troops.size());
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)client.receiveObjects();
            System.out.println("obj: " +obj.size());
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troop) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Troop){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }
        }else if(isServerActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                server.sendObjects(towers);
                System.out.println("sent towers: " + towers.size());
            }else{
                server.sendObjects(troops);
                System.out.println("sent troops: " + troops.size());
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)server.receiveObjects();
            System.out.println("obj: " +obj.size());
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troop) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Troop){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the two main methods I call to test the server, client, and troop classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Server s = new Server();
    ArrayList<Troop> troopsArray = new ArrayList<Troop>();
    troopsArray.add(new Goblin(1,1,1));
    troopsArray.add(new Goblin(2,2,2));
    s.sendObject(troopsArray);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Client c = new Client();
    while(true){
        ArrayList<Troop> troop2 = (ArrayList<Troop>)c.receiveObjects();     
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, troop2.get(1).getX());
    }
}
```

Here is the requested Handler code:

```
public class Handler implements Serializable{
private Game game;
private transient Player player;
private transient ArrayList<Tower> towers;
private transient ArrayList<Troop> troops;
private transient Screen screen;
private transient Frame frame;
private transient Menu menu;
private ArrayList<Worlds> worlds;

public Handler(Game game, Player player, ArrayList<Tower> towers, ArrayList<Troop> troops, Screen screen, Frame frame, Menu menu, ArrayList<Worlds> worlds){
    this.game = game;
    this.player = player;
    this.towers = towers;
    this.troops = troops;
    this.screen = screen;
    this.frame = frame;
    this.menu = menu;
    this.worlds = worlds;
}

public Server getServer(){
    return game.getServer();
}
public Client getClient(){
    return game.getClient();
}
public ArrayList<Worlds> getWorlds() {
    return worlds;
}

public Game getGame() {
    return game;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public ArrayList<Tower> getTowers() {
    return towers;
}

public ArrayList<Troop> getTroops() {
    return troops;
}

public Screen getScreen() {
    return screen;
}

public Frame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public Menu getMenu() {
    return menu;
}
public boolean towerCollisionWithTile(int x, int y){
    return worlds.get(game.getLevel()).getTile(x, y).isTowerNotPlaceable();
}

}
```

Worlds class:

```
public class Worlds implements Serializable{

private int width = 40;
private int height = 20; //in tiles
private int spawnX, spawnY;
private int[][]  tiles;

public Worlds(String path){
    loadWorld(path);
}

public Tile getTile(int x, int y){
    if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height)
        return Tile.grassTile;

    Tile t = Tile.tiles[tiles[x][y]];
    if(t == null)
        return Tile.grassTile;
    return t;
}



public void render(Graphics g){

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            getTile(x, y).render(g, (int) (x * Tile.TILE_WIDTH),
                        (int) (y* Tile.TILE_HEIGHT));
        }
    }
}


private void loadWorld(String path){
    String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
    String [] tokens = file.split("\\s");

    tiles = new int[width][height];

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            tiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x + y * width)]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Sorry if I posted too much code, but I'd rather have a little too much, than not enough. If it is needed I can post the contents of the console for the Errors. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Handler" is, but are you sure that is serialize-able as well as its properties? When serializing an object it must be serialize-able, along with any of its properties.

Comment: That may be the issue, I'll try fixing all of that now.

Comment: I went though and made all the classes implement serializable, but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to both Ian and CConard96. The problem was, while the class I was trying to send over was serializable, the references it made were not. In order to reduce what I was sending over the socket (and thus simplify it so that less needed to be serializable) I was able to fix the problem by using static references, eliminating them (the non-serialized classes) from being written by the ObjectOutputStream.

While transient can work, it is not ideal in this situation. It will cause the sent object to have a null reference to anything transient. So the Handler variable as well as buffered Image needed to be handed differently.

Answer (score 0):

The Handler appears to be [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) which is not serializable. You will need to make it transient like the BufferedImage.

Comment: The image has the 'transient' keyword and would be skipped during serialization. That should't be causing the error.

Comment: @CConard96 I have corrected my answer. Thanks for explaining transient better.

Comment: Handler is a class I made myself. It is a nice class where i can access all the variables from one location. It also implements serializable.

Comment: when changed it to transient, it no longer gives the serializable error, but rather throws a nullPointerException. One step closer(Maybe), but there I found the nullPointer to be related to Handler, so ill post the code

Comment: Does your Handler extend java.util.logging.Handler? Is it saying that your Handler is null?

Comment: this is the line in Troop that throws the error: protected boolean collisionWithTile(int x, int y), and Handler does not extend anything

Comment: What is your `Screen` Class?

Comment: Screen extends Jcomponent. I updated my Handler, making the variables not used by Troop transient, leaving the Game class and Worlds class. I added the code for Worlds (where I think the problem is). I'll look into both now, and add it here in case someone find the issue faster than I can

Comment: Could referencing Handler in a static way get around the Handler Issue?

Comment: Do you import `java.util.*`?

Comment: I use my own Util class, just a place to put static methods such as: calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2)